# Wireless data transmission options for streaming video

Tags: arduino, wireless, raspberry-pi, wifi, xbee

I am in the initial stages of planning a project that involves the wireless transmission of data between either an Arduino or Raspberry Pi and a base computer/RPi.

Data transmitted includes the state of a number of different environmental sensors, which have low data bandwidth requirements, but ideally I'd also like to be able to transmit a good quality video stream (ideally 720p, but at least 480p).

I see that most of the XBees have a 250kbps limit, and recognise that this is under ideal circumstances and I suspect that actual data transmission rate will be less than this, say 200kbps? So I feel think that an XBee solution is not going to be able to keep up with the data transmitted.

Anyway, **I was wondering what options I have for wireless data transfer mechanisms that would be capable of data streams better than 250kbps and with 50m+ range?**

I've started to look at modules such as [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11048), but am unsure what the expected range of such units are (see [this other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214091/how-to-determine-range-of-wifi-module) that I recently posted) and so I'm just trying to get an idea of what my options are. Cheers!

Comment: 720p will require several Mbps.  XBee and Arduino are both out.  Raspberry Pi + wifi would be a far better option.

Comment: @alex.forencich Thanks for that.  I suspected that Arduino/Xbee would not be able to handle the data rate. I'm trying to find information regarding the range of wifi modules. Can you please see my other question [posted here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214091/how-to-determine-range-of-wifi-module)? Perhaps you could help? Thanks!

Comment: The module you linked can only communicate with a UART at up to 464 kbps, too slow for video streaming.  If you want to use a raspberry pi, just get a USB wi-fi dongle.

Comment: Good point @alex.forencich. I'll do some research into USB dongles with an external antenna to try and maximise range.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before, Arduino will not be sufficient. I would go for the raspberry pi.

In terms of transmission, if you want good range, I have used these in some applications using the ethernet port, they are quite good:
https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/picostationm/

Comment: Cheers Jorge. The PicoStation looks like a pretty tidy unit with an impressive range.